# What does |= do in Python?

Tags: python

I have inherited an application that contains the following line

```
someStrict |= ufDict.get('preferencesPolicy', None) == 'strict'
```

What does the |= operator do? I can't find any documentation covering it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a in-place OR operator.

Live above is equivalent to:

```
someStrict = someStrict or ufDict.get('preferencesPolicy', None) == 'strict'
```

Basically it sets `someStrict` value only if this value wasn't falsy in a first place. Best bet is that is just fancy test for `someStrict` being `None` (as `None` is falsy in boolean context).

Comment: Also, the docs for it are here: [http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_inclusive_OR_assignment.html](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_inclusive_OR_assignment.html)

Comment: `|=` is the in-place version of `|` not `or`. The code from the question is faulty. The `get()` can return `None`, but `None` can not be a operand of `|` (or `|=`).

Comment: @KlausD. But of `==`, which is processed first.